# Getting ClassNotFoundException after changing project folder name

Tags: java, android, firebase

I recently changed my android studio project folder name and all hell broke lose. I keep getting this error whenever I try to run my application.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.natech.rokonect-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.natech.rokonect-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5430)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5000)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4940)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1549)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.natech.rokonect-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.natech.rokonect-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5415)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5000) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4940) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1549) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
                                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider
                                                                       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                            ... 12 more
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

I have already include multidex in my gradle file but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check with cleaning your project and deleting all previous build files.

Comment: Thank you. I cleaned and rebuilt the project